# Split array and compare values to separate columns

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create a function which scans a column (job-trav-seq) and splits the values in each cell within a given range. It then compares these values to comparable cells in separate columns (so for instance job-trav-seq would have a cell 58546-05-10; this function would remove the dashes and compare the 58546 to job number, 05 to traveller ID and 07 to sequence No.

Basically, the function needs to first takes the A column (JobTravSeq) and breaks it apart into individual variables. (variable 1 should be compared with values in column B, values in variable 2 should be compared with column C and values in variable 3 should be compared with column D)

A loop should go up through the column cells as long as variable 1 = values in column B and variable 2 = values in column C (this is rowStart); this should be stored as a variable

A second loop should occur (rowEnd); which should loop down though the column cells as long as variable 1 = values in column B and variable 2 = values in column C; this should be stored as a variable

The code should then traverse between rowStart and rowEnd and check if variable 3 = values in column D, if it does then place an asterisk (or something similar) in front of the value to mark it as a current task

What im starting with: [Sample Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xL1tbTu9pPTcokeLyWcPjIUeKwc0wNFB3Jg0PsnNnBU/edit#gid=733371001)

What im trying to achieve: [SampleDocOutput](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scUbps_uU8p8OYuDegSGf-ICHpHsKA8bTrkHf3Q5B9s/edit)

any help would be most appreciated

heres my code for reference:

```
Sub SampleDocOrganise()

Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow, rowCompare As Long
Dim variArr, rowStart, rowEnd, rangeID As Variant
Dim JobTravSeqRng As Range, jobNoRng As Range, TravellerRng As Range, 
opSeqRng As Range, _
rng_JobTravSeq As Range, rng_JobNo As Range, rng_Traveller As Range, 
rng_opSeq As Range

Set JobTravSeqRng = Range("A:A")
Set jobNoRng = Range("B:B")
Set TravellerRng = Range("C:C")
Set opSeqRng = Range("D:D")

For Each JobTravSeq In Selection
Str_Array = Split(JobTravSeq, "-")

    For h = 0 To UBound(Str_Array)
       Range("A:A").Find (Str_Array)
       Range.Offset(, h + 1) = Str_Array(h)

     For rowStart = 4 To Rows.Count
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Str_Array, 1).Value = jobNoRng.Value Then

          If Cells(Str_Array, 2).Value = jobNoRng.Value Then
              Cells.Value = rowStart
          End If

        End If

     Next rowStart

     For rowEnd = LastRow To 4 Step -1
          If Cells(Str_Array, 1).Value = Range("B:B").Value Then
                 If Cells(Str_Array, 2).Value = Range("C:C").Value Then
                       Cells.Value = rowEnd
                 End If
          End If
     Next rowEnd

     For rowCompare = rowStart To rowEnd
         For Each opSeqArr In Str_Array
            If Cells(Str_Array, 3).Value = Range("D:D").Value Then
                If Cells(Str_Array, 1).Value = Range("B:B") Then
                    ActiveCell.Characters(0, 0).Insert (" P ")
                        With ActiveCell.Characters(0, Len(" P ")).Font
                           .Name = "OpSeq_Equals"
                           .Bold = True
                           .Color = -16776961
                        End With
                        MsgBox cell.Value = "*" & ""

                      ' if cell changes then go to next loop

                 Else

                      ' if cell changes then go to next loop
                 End If
            End If
         Next
      Next
   Next h
 Next
 End Sub

Sub MsgboxTasks() 'should display all rows that contain an asterisk in opSeq (current tasks)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where have you defined that function?

Comment: at the top. ill be honest i dont have a lot of experience with vba

Comment: Did you name it `IsInArray`? Or did you get that from some tutorial? Because you defined it as an array, but its name looks more like it would be a function.

Comment: i got it from some part of the existing codebase, ill probably wipe it out because its just not working